# Зацикливается редактирование бинарного файла Си

Tags: c, файлы, циклы

Необходимо заменить каждое третье число в бинарном файле на то же число с противоположным знаком. Числа представлены типа double. При попытке перезаписать часть файла происходит зацикливание.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_PATH 261

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input_file;
    char *filename;
    int n = 0;
    double number;
    filename = (char*) malloc (MAX_PATH*sizeof(char));
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("Enter filename: ");
        scanf ("%s", filename);
    }   else filename = argv[1];
    if ((input_file = fopen (filename, "r+b")) == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Cannot open input file");
        return 1;
    }
    while (!feof(input_file))
    {
        n += fread (&number, sizeof(double), 1, input_file);
        if (n % 3 == 0 && n != 0)
        {
            number *= -1;
            fseek (input_file, (n-1)*sizeof(double), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite (&number, sizeof(double), 1, input_file);
        }
    }
    fclose (input_file);
    free (filename);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: После чтения вы fseek делаете, как же вы сможете до-конца файл дочитать? Да ещё при позицировании на -1 относительно текущего.

Comment: основная ошибка в том, что надо контролировать, что возвращает `fread`, и в ту же степь — проверка на `feof` должна быть после `fread`'а...

Answer (score 2):

> For files open for update (those which include a "+" sign), on which both input and output operations are allowed, the stream shall be flushed (fflush) or repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) before a reading operation that follows a writing operation.

Это требование не выполняется у вас в программе - после `fwrite` нужно опять вызвать `fseek`.

Comment: На какую позицию должно быть смещение? Не могу подобрать